# How do I capture string between certain Character and String in multi line String? Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let's say we have a string

```
string="This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] >(ascd asdfas -were)\

 test \

(testing test) test >asdf  \

       test"
```

I need to get the string between character > and string "test".

I tried

```
re.findall(r'>[^)](.*)test',string, re.MULTILINE )
```

However I get

```
(ascd asdfas -were)\ test \ (testing test) test >asdf.
```

However I need:

```
(ascd asdfas -were)\
```

AND

```
asdf
```

How can I get those 2 string?

Comment: So, I attempted to fix your code blocks, can you confirm they're as you intended?

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted

Comment: Here's a great regex builder help you test https://regex101.com/#python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
import re

s="""This is a test code [asdf -wer -a2 asdf] >(ascd asdfas -were)
test
(testing test) test >asdf
test"""

print(re.findall(r'>(.*?)\btest\b', s, re.DOTALL))
```

Output:

```
['(ascd asdfas -were)\n', 'asdf\n']
```

The only somewhat interesting parts of this pattern are:

- `.*?`, where `?` makes the `.*` "ungreedy", otherwise you'd have a single, long match instead of two.
- Using `\btest\b` as the "ending" identifier (see Jan's comment below) instead of `test`. [Where](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax),

  > `\b`
  > Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word....

Note, it may be reading up on [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), as I think that's *really* what you want.  `DOTALL` lets `.` characters include newlines, while [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) lets anchors (`^`, `$`) match start and end of lines instead of the entire string.  Considering you don't use anchors, I'm thinking `DOTALL` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the explanation as well. I will accept this answer  as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: Please be aware that this will match `test` in `tester`, `testerfield`, `testman` (you get the idea) as well - apply word boundaries as well: `\btest\b`.